# Why do I get the Fibonacci sequence when I start with 1 and keep using the + sign?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, calculator

I played with this on a calculator and when I entered 1 and kept hitting the + button, I got the noticeable Fibonacci sequence!  Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1+1=2\\
1+2=3\\
2+3=5\\
3+5=8$$

So your calculator is adding the current number to the previous term of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Your calculator may also have a Polish notation setting, allowing you to do the Fibbonacci Series.